# Sprite Object not being shown on display (Pygame)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am currently trying to develop a small, basic game using Pygame. However, I am not able to draw my sprite object onto the screen. My code is below:

```
import pygame

# window
WIDTH = 400
HEIGHT = 400
FPS = 60

# colors
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
PINK = (255, 0, 191)
BROWN = (102, 51, 0)
GRAY = (102, 102, 51)

# player

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50,50))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)

        # variables needed for movement
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = 200
        self.rect.bottom = 200
        self.speedx = 0
        self.speedy = 0

    def update(self):
        # move sprite
        self.speedx = 0
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_w]:
            self.speedx = -5
        if keystate[pygame.K_d]:
            self.speedx = 5
        self.rect.x += self.speedx

        # boundary collision
        if self.rect.x < 0:
            self.rect.x = 0
        elif self.rect.x < 400:
            self.rect.x = 400


# initialisation
pygame.init()

# sound
pygame.mixer.init()

# draw window
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Shoot")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# sprite group
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

# create player
player = Player()

# add sprites to sprite group
all_sprites.add(player)

# game loop

running = True
while running:
    # keeps speed constant
    clock.tick(FPS)
    # allows for exit
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # check before closing window
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # update sprites
    all_sprites.update()

    # draw screen
    #screen.fill(BLACK)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    #player.draw(screen)
    # used to draw
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

As you can see in the code, I have a player object which I create from the Player class. I then add this to an all_sprites group. This should then be drawn on the screen. However, nothing is drawn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the rectangle of the `Player` object is out of the window, because of `if self.rect.x < 400: self.rect.x = 400` in:

> ```py
> class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
>    # [...]
>
>    def update(self):
>        # [...]
>
>        if self.rect.x < 0:
>            self.rect.x = 0
>        elif self.rect.x < 400:
>            self.rect.x = 400
> ```

It has to be `self.rect.x > 400`:

```py
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]

    def update(self):
        # [...]

        if self.rect.x < 0:
            self.rect.x = 0
        elif self.rect.x > 400: # <----
            self.rect.x = 400
```